# FFmpeg (merge two audio)

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have two long audio files. I want to merge cut some part from each video
and merge both parts in one file.

In below command the problem there is no audio in the second audio part. It contain the first part and the second is empty.

What is the problem?

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=black 
-ss 157.824 -t 99.818 
-i "file1.mp4" 
-ss 315.764 -t 50.308 
-i "file2.mp4" 
-s 854x480 
-aspect 1.779167
-r 25 
-c:v libx264 
-b:v 800k 
-c:a aac 
-strict experimental 
-b:a 128k 
-f mp4 
-t 150.126 -async 1 
-y "output.mp4"
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to concatenate the trimmed `file1.mp4` & `file2.mp4`? What are you using the color source filter for?

Comment: both files is audio mp4, when I merge it (the first audio working fine the second is empty )